# Show/hide fragment on button click in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to know how to show and hide a fragment on a button click in Android. When button is in clicked state then fragment should appear, and when the button is clicked again then the fragment should disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and it worked for me. First I added the fragment when button is clicked for first time and then on subsequent clicks I attached and detached it. So it created the fragment and then without destroying it only showed and hid it.

this is the code.... Initially count is 0 when the MainActivity is first created

```
       public void Settings(View view){

       if(count==0){
       count++;
       // add a fragment for the first time
        MyFragment frag=new MyFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft=manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.group,frag,"A");
        ft.commit();
        }else{

        //check if fragment is visible, if no, then attach a fragment 
        //else if its already visible,detach it 
        Fragment frag=manager.findFragmentByTag("A");
        if(frag.isVisible() && frag!=null){
            FragmentTransaction ft=manager.beginTransaction();
            ft.detach(frag);
            ft.commit();
        }else{
            FragmentTransaction ft=manager.beginTransaction();
            ft.attach(frag);
            ft.commit();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Attach and detach forces OnCreate method to run every time fragment is attached, which is what i wanted for my case. Attach/detach works much better than Hide/Show.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Dialog fragment for this purpose. Dialog Fragment has all life cycle as fragment has and has behavior like dialog. 
For example to show, simply call dialogFragment.show() method, and to hide, call dialogFragment.dismiss() method.

Here is an example how to make a dialog fragment.

```
public class DialogFragmentExample  extends DialogFragment{


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
// To make dialog fragment full screen.
    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    if (dialog != null) {
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    }
//
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_xml_layout, container, false);
}

// initialize your views here

}
```

And to show this dialog fragment;

```
DialogFragmentExample fragment = new DialogFragmentExample();
fragment.show();
```

similarly to dismiss,

```
fragment.dismiss();
```

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Fragment Transaction's internal show/hide flag will help.

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction()
          .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
          .show(somefrag) //or hide(somefrag)
          .commit();
```